# How to scrollToBottom in Flatlist with dynamic height content?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

The contents of my `Flatlist` have variable height. The methods `scrollToIndex`, `scrollToItem` require `getItemLayout` prop to be set. I guess measuring each and every content will slow down the performance of the `Flatlist` as the list has hundred's of rows. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this?